# Bootstrap fluid layout - fixed width of sidebar

Tags: css, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

i have a fluid layout based of twitters bootstrap.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
       <div class="span2">
           <!--Sidebar content-->
       </div>
       <div class="span10">
           <!--Body content-->
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It would be very nice to have the sidebar a fixed width. if a change the layout from fluid to "static" and set the width of sidebar to

```
220px
```

and i resize the window or change my resolution to 1024... the body-content jumps under the sidebar. how can i avoid this?

EDIT:
Got it. Will post my "solution" later on. thanks for your responses

Comment: Can you put up a test case using something like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? Can't quite understand the effect you're looking for here.

Comment: So... what was this famous "solution" of yours? :)

Comment: Yes, post your solution, I'm also interested, fixed width sidebar with the rest of page fluid... I can't accomplish that

Comment: Here's a solution: http://ekdhl.net/blog/2012/10/19/fixed-width-static-sidebar-with-twitter-bootstrap-fluid-layout/

Comment: "I have found a truly remarkable solution to this problem, but I can't fit it in a stackoverflow comment." --Jens. ;)

Answer (score 31):

I think you are looking something like this:

```
<div class="sidebar span4">
    this is my fixed sidebar
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2">this is fluid</div>
            <div class="span3 offset1">yeah!</div>
            <div class="span6">Awesome!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">1 half</div>
            <div class="span6">2 half</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here´s a fiddle for your convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/TT8uV/2/

As as general note:

> You don´t need to use bootstrap as your 'main container', so you can place your 
>   sidebar side-by-side with a grid system (like bootstrap
>   fluid and responsive). This way you have ***A LOT*** of control of the
>   sidebar, without affecting the actual content.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: This is the only answer that solved the fixed width. The others are about fixed position. +1

Comment: I appreciate this attempt, but the problem is, the second row in the right hand main floats lower than the bottom of the right-hand sidebar. Notice how '1 half' and '2 half' (which are spans in the second row-fluid in the main nav) float below it: http://jsfiddle.net/TT8uV/2/show/

Comment: I don't think this has to be with the solution, but either way I update with an overflow:auto to the row here: http://jsfiddle.net/TT8uV/35/ or you can postion:absolute the sidebar http://jsfiddle.net/TT8uV/36/

Comment: This is the proper solution - you don't need to use the Bootstrap grid for everything. Having a separate sidebar is the best. Please accept this answer!

Answer (score 8):

I think this is what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/U8HGz/1/

Comment: nope, because the sidebar is fixed in position. my right row/container has a width of mh approx 3000-4000px. so if i scroll right the sidebar is always on top.
but thanks for your response