# Fixed position sidebar according to viewport (fluid layout)

Tags: css, css-position, fluid-layout

In a CSS fluid layout all divs use percentages. However, I need my sidebar to have a fixed position.

Example:

```
<aside style="width:25%; float:left; position:fixed;">
    aside content
</aside>
<div style="width:75%; float:left;">
    main content    
</div>
```

What I'm really trying to do is to make the sidebar keep a specific width according to the viewport. For example I need it to be 300px wide if the viewport is between 1000 and 1200 px wide.

An alternative: I also want it to be 300px wide when its parent div (I know I din't mention a parent div in the example above) is larger than say 1000px.

I guess it takes some JS to do it but I'm a *complete idiot* when it comes to JS so your help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) { div#sidebar { width: 300px; }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a **CSS media query**

Example

```
@media all and (min-width:1000px) and  (max-width:1200px)
{
  // css 
}

@media all and (min-width:300px) and (max-width:1000px)
{
   // css 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like duplicate of : [Bootstrap fluid layout - fixed width of sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589333/bootstrap-fluid-layout-fixed-width-of-sidebar)

My answer there :

I think you are looking something like this:

```
<div class="sidebar span4">
    this is my fixed sidebar
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2">this is fluid</div>
            <div class="span3 offset1">yeah!</div>
            <div class="span6">Awesome!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">1 half</div>
            <div class="span6">2 half</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here´s a fiddle for your convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/TT8uV/2/

As as general note:

> You don´t need to use bootstrap as your 'main container', so you can place your 
>   sidebar side-by-side with a grid system (like bootstrap
>   fluid and responsive). This way you have ***A LOT*** of control of the
>   sidebar, without affecting the actual content.

Hope it works for you.